# When exactly does the ordering of the hash map keys are affected,

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode, hash-collision

I know that there is no guarantee in the order of the keys in the hashmap.
Will the reordering happen if there is no rehashing or hash collision?

Comment: It should not happen until you add new keys but it may vary for java version.

Comment: I know that it will not happen if there is only one key !!. My question was even if we add multiple keys sometimes the order is maintained, I wanted to know the exact case when and why the order is altered.

Comment: StackFlowed explained to you that it will not happen until you add another key to the map, regardless of the current map size.

Comment: And if you meant to say that the _insertion order_ is maintained, that's simply untrue. Insertion order is never maintained unless by accident (you happen to insert keys in just the order they will eventually assume).

Comment: And if you add a new key, and there's no rehashing, the order of the rest of the entries will stay the same as `addEntry()` will just add the new entry to the start of the entry list of one of the buckets, and the iterator returns them left-to-right and in bucket order.

Comment: But the problem is that `HashMap` is not `final`, so a subclass can (and will) change this behaviour without you noticing it. And of course the implementation of `HashMap` itself can change too.

Comment: Long story short, there is nothing really useful to say about this question.

Answer (score 4):

We really are not supposed to worry about that!

On inspection of the source code for HashMap, it seems that internally it uses an array of HashMap.Entry objects, and the array index used to find the required entry is based on the hashCode() of the object and the size of the array. So the ordering is related to the object's hashCode and the size of the Map.

This is a simplification, however, and I only looked at the implementation in OpenJDK 6.

You should never rely on the implementation details. There's a good reason why there's an interface called Map: that defines how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in `java.util.HashMap` entries are moved and reordered only upon hitting maximum threshold. 
The method `addEntry()` invokes `resize()` method, which transfers to a new table rearranges the keys

```
768     void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
         //
771         if (size++ >= threshold)
772             resize(2 * table.length);


471    void resize(int newCapacity) {
         //
479         Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
480         transfer(newTable);
481         table = newTable;
```

Comment: That's rehashing and OP already excluded it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this interesting [link](http://coding-geek.com/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java/) it exposes in detail how Hashmap works:
Here is how put and get work as explained:

> All the keys with the same hash value are put in the same linked list (bucket). Keys with different hash values can end-up in the same bucket.
>
> When a user calls put(K key, V value) or get(Object key), the function computes the index of the bucket in which the Entry should be. Then, the function iterates through the list to look for the Entry that has the same key (using the equals() function of the key).
>
> In the case of the get(), the function returns the value associated with the entry (if the entry exists).
>
> In the case of the put(K key, V value), if the entry exists the function replaces it with the new value otherwise it creates a new entry (from the key and value in arguments) at the head of the singly linked list.